# d3.js - convert ordinal scale to linear scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a scatter graph. For my Y dimension I have an ordinal scale based off an array, something like this:

```
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
```

Rather than use the actual string values - and therefore requiring an ordinal scale - I would like to instead plot the array index number of each category in my colours array.

My theory is that this means I could then use a linear scale instead of an ordinal one. Is this thinking correct? If so how do I go about setting this up? I'm struggling to find the right approach. (The purpose of this is prep for using the d3 zoom feature since it doesn't seem to like ordinal scales.)

Here is the rest of my current code in question:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
   .domain([
        d3.min(dataset, d => d.event_date),
        d3.max(dataset, d => d.event_date)
    ])
   .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scalePoint()
   .domain(dataset.map(function(d){return d.colours;});
   .range([0, height]);
```

I then go on to plot circles to create a scatter graph.

Comment: Could you provide some sort of example? It's not clear what the problem is with the above approach

Comment: Hi @Dominic i am also trying to implement the same approach. But now solving countless other things to make the scale only take the array index. As soon as my graph height becomes more it starts giving the scale in 0.5 or even 0.1